# Moment-Timezone is not changing the date/time for the specified region

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, momentjs

I am using moment and moment-timezone to output the airdate/time of a given TV Show (for any timezone)

The host timezone is America/Chicago

In the example below, the `dateTime` passed in is a TV show that airs in 3 hours. Which is Sunday at 9:00PM in America/Chicago, and Monday at 4:00 AM in Europe/Zagreb:

```
  determineAirTime(dateTime) {
    console.log(dateTime); // July 16th 2017 9:00PM

    dateTime = 
 momentTimezone.tz(dateTime, "MMM Do YYYY hA", momentTimezone.tz.guess());

    dateTime = dateTime.format(); // this creates: 2017-07-16T21:00:00-05:00

   // moment
   moment(dateTime).calendar(); // Today at 9:00 PM
  }
```

For my timezone (America/Chicago), `Today at 9:00 PM` is correct. However, it always outputs `Sunday 9:00 pm` for any timezone, which is incorrect.

Here is an example of the same data we used in our example, but with a different timezone:

[image]

The correct output for the above would be `Monday at 4:00 AM`.

How can I fix my program so that it prints out the correct air/date times for the timezone?

Comment: It's much better to post text rather than images. Given that Zagreb is UTC+01:00 then 2017-07-23T21:00:00+02:00 is 2017-07-23T20:00:00+01:00. Why do you think the time should be 04:00? America/Chicago is UTC-06:00, so that would be 2017-07-23T13:00:00-06:00 or 1pm.

Comment: it's 1:23am in Zagreb, the airtime for my example is 3 hours from now, so the output should be Monday at 4:00 AM. Or something close to that

Comment: Perhaps you should specify some precise inputs, outputs and offsets. Your question isn't clear.

Comment: I'll try and rephrase the question

Comment: In your question, what is the value of *dateTime*? What is the value of *thing*? What is the host timezone?

Comment: The value of dateTime is "July 16th 2017 9:00PM", all the values are shown in comments next each line of code. The host timezone is America/Chicago

Comment: "July 16th 2017 9:00PM" doesn't have an associated time zone so it represents 9pm in every time zone. You must provide an associated offset in order to fix it at a particular moment in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start with a date string for UTC-06:00 on 23 July at 21:00, then you'll have a date like:

```
var s = '2017-07-23T21:00:00-0600';
```

To output that in an equivalent timezone for say Zagreb which is UTC+01:00, use:

```js
var s = '2017-07-23T21:00:00-0600';
var d = moment(s);

console.log('America/Chicago: ' + 
             d.tz('America/Chicago').format('dddd D MMMM, YYYY hh:mm a'));

console.log('Europe/Zagreb: ' + 
             d.tz('Europe/Zagreb').format('dddd D MMMM, YYYY hh:mm a'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.13/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a shot

Answer (score 2):

Observe:

```
var dateTime = 'July 16th 2017 9:00PM';  // as you said in your question

// create a moment object in the original time zone
var m = moment.tz(dateTime, 'MMM Do YYYY h:mmA', 'America/Chicago');

// switch to the target time zone and format back to a string
var s = m.tz('Europe/Zagreb').format('MMM Do YYYY h:mmA');  // 'Jul 17th 2017 4:00AM'
```

Also, in your code you used `moment.tz.guess()`.  That is unnecessary.  If you meant to use the local time zone, then just call the `local` function.  In other words, change the last line of what I wrote above to:

```
var s = m.local().format('MMM Do YYYY h:mmA');
```